# Зачем нужен класс Void?

Tags: java

Зачем в Java нужен класс `java.lang.Void`?

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643906/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`void.class == Void.TYPE` вернет `true` - таким образом, в большинстве случаев (например, если нужно через рефлексию проверить возвращаемый тип метода) можно (и, на мой взгляд, стоит) использовать `void.class` - яснее и ненароком не перепутаешь с `Void.class`. Так что использовать его можно, например, в случаях, когда у вас есть обобщенный класс и вы хотите, чтобы метод ничего не возвращал (т.е. чтобы пользователь класса не ожидал ничего особенного оттуда получить):

```
interface I<T> {
    T doStuff();
}

class A implements I<Void> {
    @Override
    public Void doStuff() {
        // ...
        return null; // ничего другого вернуть нельзя (если не хитрить с рефлексией, конечно)
    }
}
```

**UPD.**
Например, если в проекте регулярно используется [`Callable<t>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) для выполнения каких-то асинхронных задач и не хочется мешать его со `Thread` в тех ситуациях, когда результат работы задачи ничего не должен возвращать, можно реализовать `Callable<Void>`.

Comment: Непонятно другое, **зачем** делать такие интерфейсы и так их реализовывать ? Какой-нибудь осмысленный с практической точки зрения пример, пожалуйста.

Comment: Проксирование или обертывание вызовов каких-нибудь методов в каком-нибудь расширяемом фреймворке или, например, в интерпретаторе.

Comment: забавно, @ХэшКод это баг или фича, что в тексте указано `Callable<T>` (T - прописная), в предпросмотре она тоже прописная, в результате строчная?

Comment: Работает: https://ideone.com/JbLAXx :)

Answer (score 2):

Класс `Void` - это неинстанциируемый класс-плейсхолдер, содержащий ссылку на Class-объект для ключевого слова `void`.

Источник: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html

> The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.