# Какой смысл такого списка?

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist

```
ArrayList<Void> arr = new ArrayList<Void>();
```

Что можно хранить в таком листе?

Answer (score 16):

Да собственно ничего и не сможешь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD**
По идее, есть хорошее описание в другом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/42543/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-void). Поэтому, да, как и говорилось в соседнем ответе, можно добавить в список null, а вот возвращать метод `.get(0)` уже ничего не будет.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 11):

Класс Void это неинициализируемый класс, содержащий в себе объект Class  от ключевого слова java - void.
В таком листе можно хранить null.
Целесообразность такого очень сомнительна. Хороший ответ дан https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/42567/181210